# Laravel 5.1, using variable's name in view files

Tags: php, smarty, laravel-5.1

Can somebody explain why the next thing doesn't work in laravel 5.1:
I've view file login1.blade.php

```
@extends('ajaxforms.form1')
@section('form')
<input type="text" name="email" /><input type="password" name="password" />
@endsection
@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">var modalName = '#{{$modalname}}';</script>
@endsection
@section('link')
<li ng-controller="login_controller" id="login_controller">
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$modalname}}">Sign in</a></li>
@endsection
```

register1.blade.php

```
@extends('ajaxforms.form1')
@section('form')
<input type="text" name="name" /><input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="password" name="password" /><input type="password2" name="password2" />
@endsection
@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">var modalName = '#{{$modalname}}';</script>
@endsection
@section('link')
<li ng-controller="register_controller" id="register_controller">
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$modalname}}">Sign in</a></li>
@endsection
```

..and form1.blade.php

```
<div id="{{ $modalname }}">
@yield('form')
</div>
@yield('script')
@yield('link')
```

And also links in a master.blade.php:

```
@include('ajaxforms.login1',['modalname' => 'modalLogin'])
@include('ajaxforms.register1', ['modalname' => 'modalRegister'])
```

This generates a code:

```
<div id="modalLogin">
<input type="text" name="email" /><input type="password" name="password" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var modalName = '#modalLogin';</script>
<li ng-controller="login_controller" id="login_controller">
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLogin">Sign in</a></li>

<div id="modalRegister">
<input type="text" name="email" /><input type="password" name="password" />
</div>
<!--Here I want to '#modalRegister' instead of '#modalLogin'; And register_controller 
instead of login_controller. Why doesn't work?????????????????????????-->
<script type="text/javascript">var modalName = '#modalLogin';</script>
<li ng-controller="login_controller" id="login_controller">
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLogin">Sign in</a></li>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the section definition, You are using two different section with same name for same request.
If section **form** is once defined it is cached and used later with same code.
[This link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-can-i-include-blade-partials-with-same-section-name-multiple-times) can give the other way around.